# python3 - I need 4\u0000\ but instead get 4\x00\

Tags: python, json

I utterly do not understand the below :

I need to send a message in json that looks like this:

```
ff = "4\x00\xe6\x8c\xc0b\x02c\x023\x02\x01\x02\x00\xe2\xea\xa8\xab\x02\xd6\x92\xe8\x87\x02\x88\xfd\x01\x0ez\x94\x01\x02B\x02\x00\x02\x00\x00"  

print (json.dumps({"a":ff}))

{"a": "4\u0000\u00e6\u008c\u00c0b\u0002c\u00023\u0002\u0001\u0002\u0000\u00e2\u00ea\u00a8\u00ab\u0002\u00d6\u0092\u00e8\u0087\u0002\u0088\u00fd\u0001\u000ez\u0094\u0001\u0002B\u0002\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000"}
```

However the orignal looks like this in python:

```
gg =  b'4\x00\xe6\x8c\xc0b\x02c\x023\x02\x01\x02\x00\xe2\xea\xa8\xab\x02\xd6\x92\xe8\x87\x02\x88\xfd\x01\x0ez\x94\x01\x02B\x02\x00\x02\x00\x00'



print (json.dumps({"a": repr(gg)[2:-1]}))

{"a": "4\\x00\\xe6\\x8c\\xc0b\\x02c\\x023\\x02\\x01\\x02\\x00\\xe2\\xea\\xa8\\xab\\x02\\xd6\\x92\\xe8\\x87\\x02\\x88\\xfd\\x01\\x0ez\\x94\\x01\\x02B\\x02\\x00\\x02\\x00\\x00"}
```

I really don't understand the difference but I need to send messages with the u0 and not the other.  How do I resolve?  Whats the difference?

What I need is ff to be dumped as gg.

Why ?  I am passing messages from python to go via zmq and decoding avro from go.  When I hard code the binary as a string (ff) all works in go.  When I have a binary in python and convert it to string and send to go it cant decode.  I get my json to have the \U over the \x I am good.

UPDATE:

If I did the below it worked:

```
json.dumps({"a": gg.decode('unicode-escape') })
{"a": "4\u0000\u00e6\u008c\u00c0b\u0002c\u00023\u0002\u0001\u0002\u0000\u00e2\u00ea\u00a8\u00ab\u0002\u00d6\u0092\u00e8\u0087\u0002\u0088\u00fd\u0001\u000ez\u0094\u0001\u0002B\u0002\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000"}
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So, JSON doesn't have the concept of binary blobs. Perhaps you could serialize the data differently over your transport layer?

Comment: _passing messages from python to go via zmq and decoding avro from go_. -- Then why not use `fastavro` in python?

Comment: I use fastarvo but decoding on the streamer is too slow since doing 600K per second

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the bytes to a string. The problem is - what is the correct character set for the string? I tried using 'windows-1252' by using

```
print (json.dumps({"a": str(gg, 'windows-1252')}))
```

but got

`"4\u0000\u00e6\u0152\u00c0b\u0002c\u00023\u0002\u0001\u0002\u0000\u00e2\u00ea\u00a8\u00ab\u0002\u00d6\u2019\u00e8\u2021\u0002\u02c6\u00fd\u0001\u000ez\u201d\u0001\u0002B\u0002\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000"`

which is similar but not identical. I tried 'utf-8' but that failed with a

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: invalid continuation byte
```

so no go there. But I think that's your path forward.

[repl.it here](https://repl.it/join/lyakxbjv-bobjarvis)